# SQL - Pulling entries previous date when row entries is dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a table filled with an opportunities history down to the product level. If an opportunity has 3 products, there will be 3 row entries for this one opportunity. Shown below:

```
AccNum OppNum  Product SnapshotDate  NextStep
  1      1      AAA     2019-04-02   Reach out and gauge interest
  2      1      CCC     2019-04-02   Decision on hold due to paperwork
  2      1      CCC     2019-03-31   NULL
  2      1      CCC     2019-03-24   NULL
  2      2      AAA     2019-04-02   Bid May. Discuss details w/ Vela
  2      2      BBB     2019-04-02   Bid May. Discuss details w/ Vela
  2      2    AAA-Inst. 2019-04-02   Bid May. Discuss details w/ Vela
  2      2      AAA     2019-03-31   Bid May
  2      2      BBB     2019-03-31   Bid May
  2      2    AAA-Inst. 2019-03-31   Bid May
```

The goal is to pull the previous SnapshotDate, and the previous NextStep to see if the values in NextStep has changed between the most recent snapshot and the one before it.

The ideal table would be like this (I want to do what I did to SnapshotDate to the NextStep Column, I wasn't able to make the fit on the forum page):

```
AccNum OppNum  Product SnapshotDate  SnapshotDatePrev
  1      1      AAA     2019-04-02   2019-03-31
  2      1      CCC     2019-04-02   2019-03-31
  2      1      CCC     2019-03-31   2019-03-24
  2      1      CCC     2019-03-24   2019-03-17
  2      2      AAA     2019-04-02   2019-03-31
  2      2      BBB     2019-04-02   2019-03-31
  2      2    AAA-Inst. 2019-04-02   2019-03-31
  2      2      AAA     2019-03-31   2019-03-24
  2      2      BBB     2019-03-31   2019-03-24
  2      2    AAA-Inst. 2019-03-31   2019-03-24
```

Here's what I've done. I can't properly pull the previous SnapshotDate. I'm only able to pull the row prior to the current with the lead function. I haven't been able to deal with the multiple rows per one entry based on the amount of products. (See AccNum: 2 OppNum: 2)

```
create table GTM.dbo.Table_History
(
    AccNum int,
    OppNum int,
    Product nvarchar(50),
    SnapshotDate date,
    NextStep nvarchar(150)
)
insert into GTM.dbo.Table_History
values
    (1,1,'AAA','2019-04-02','Reach out and gauge interest'),
    (2,1,'CCC','2019-04-02','Decision on hold due to paperwork'),
    (2,1,'CCC','2019-03-31',NULL),
    (2,1,'CCC','2019-03-24',NULL),
    (2,2,'AAA','2019-04-02','Bid May. Discuss details w/ Vela'),
    (2,2,'BBB','2019-04-02','Bid May. Discuss details w/ Vela'),
    (2,2,'AAA-Inst.','2019-04-02','Bid May. Discuss details w/ Vela'),
    (2,2,'AAA','2019-03-31','Bid May'),
    (2,2,'BBB','2019-03-31','Bid May'),
    (2,2,'AAA-Inst.','2019-03-31','Bid May')

SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT 
AccNum
,OppNum
,Product
,convert(DATE,DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,GETDATE()), -1)) AS PrevSun
,SnapshotDate
,lead(SnapshotDate) OVER (PARTITION BY AccNum, OppNum ORDER BY SnapshotDate DESC) AS SnapshotDatePrev
,NextStep
,lead(NextStep) OVER (PARTITION BY AccNum, OppNum ORDER BY SnapshotDate DESC) AS NextStepprev
FROM GTM.DBO.Table_History) t1
WHERE t1.SnapshotDatePrev>=t1.PrevSun
```

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So you want the previous, and the "previous previous" values? If so, have you had a look at the 2nd parameter for `LEAD` and `LAG`?

Comment: I just want the previous value for SnapshotDate for that opportunity. I edited a column in the original post hopefully it cleared up some confusion. I Know Lead/Lag's second parameter is an offset but I don't know how to incorporate an expression that would cover scenarios like AccNum-OppNum (2-2) where there's 3 rows for one opportunity. The row per opportunity is different at every opportunity. Some will have 1 row, some will have 3 or 2. It also means if they add a product overtime, row changes from 1 to 2. It also doesn't help cover entries where there is only 1 entry (new opportunity).